# c# - "Input string was not in a correct format" on my windows form when I try to calculate values

Tags: c#, string, input, format

On my form I am trying to produce results where the data entered into the textboxes are added and displayed in a label below them. When I debug the form and click the buttons they always give me back the "input string was not in a correct format" response. What can I tinker with in the code to fix this error?

```
namespace practice_calculation
{
    public partial class Calculation : Form
    {
        //setting variables for input 
         Int32 int1 = 0;
         Int32 int2 = 0;
         Int32 intSum = 0;
         decimal dec1 = 0m;
         decimal dec2 = 0m;
         decimal decSum = 0m;
         double dbl1 = 0;
         double dbl2 = 0;
         double dblSum = 0;

        public Calculation()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void integer_Calculate_Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {           
            try
            {
                Int32 int1; // to hold integer 1 value
                Int32 int2; // to hold integer 2 value
                Int32 intSum; // to hold the sum of int1 and int2

                // Get the values
                int1 = Int32.Parse(int1_Masked_Text_Box.Text);
                int2 = Int32.Parse(int2_Masked_Text_Box.Text);
                intSum = Int32.Parse(int_Results_Label.Text);

                // Calculate the Sum
                intSum = (int1 + int2);

                // Display the Sum
                int_Results_Label.Text = intSum.ToString("n1");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Display the error message.
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private void exitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //close form
            this.Close();
        }

        private void dec_Calculate_Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                Decimal dec1;  // to hold decimal 1 value
                Decimal dec2;  // to hold decimal 2 value
                Decimal decSum;  // to hold sum of dec1 and dec2

                // Get the values
                dec1 = Decimal.Parse(dec1_Masked_Text_Box.Text);
                dec2 = Decimal.Parse(dec2_Masked_Text_Box.Text);
                decSum = Decimal.Parse(dec_Results_Label.Text);

                // Calculate the Sum
                decSum = (dec1 + dec2);

                //Display the Sum
                dec_Results_Label.Text = decSum.ToString("n1");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Display the error message.
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private void dbl_Calculate_Buttons_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                Double dbl1; // to hold double 1 value
                Double dbl2; // to hold double 2 value
                Double dblSum; // to hold sum of dbl1 and dbl2

                // Get the values
                dbl1 = Double.Parse(dbl1_Masked_Text_Box.Text);
                dbl2 = Double.Parse(dbl2_Masked_Text_Box.Text);
                dblSum = Double.Parse(dbl_Results_Label.Text);

                // Calculate the Sum
                dblSum = (dbl1 + dbl2);

                //Display the Sum
                dbl_Results_Label.Text = decSum.ToString("n1");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Display the error message.
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Set breakpoints on _each_ MessageBox.Show(...) calls inside your `catch`-blocks. When one of the breakpoints hits, inspect the exception in the `ex` variable. Its stack trace will tell you exactly which line inside your try-catch-blocks threw that exception...

Comment: You need to make sure the input string is in a correct format when passing it to `Int32.Parse()`. For example, you could restrict the textbox to allow only numeric characters, and restrict the length so that any number entered will fit into an `Int32`.

Comment: *What can I tinker with...* If by "tinker" you mean debug, look at the text being parsed one if probably an empty string.  **[Navigating through Code with the Step Debugger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx)**

Comment: Why are you reading the sum (`decSum`) from the label (?) and then immediately reassigning the actual result of the arithmetic (`dec1 + dec2`) to it?  That's a good place to start.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the error of your code is in the label, you should convert the result after calculating it. Unless the text in your label is Integer. That's why it was giving you an error **input string was not in a correct format**. If you r label is blank, or has a `null` value, that cannot be parsed to an int.

Try this.

```
        Int32 int1;
        Int32 int2;
        Int32 intsum;

        int1 = Int32.Parse(textBox1.Text);
        int2 = Int32.Parse(textBox2.Text);
        //intsum = Int32.Parse(label1.Text);

        intsum = int1 + int2;

        label1.Text = intsum.ToString("n1");
```